# opposite of free

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking for the antonym of free in the sense of liberal.

> non free country

A country where something is not legal is not free.

PS. I read other questions but I could not find any suitable for this situation.

Comment: Restricted social policy? I think you'll have to be more specific about the type of freedom you mean.  Some countries levels of free are very different than others, even amongst non-free countries.

Comment: You may need to clarify more about your question.  A truly "free" country is called an "anarchy", a country with no laws; only in such a country would everything be legal.  If you are looking for a country that has the most restrictive laws, it is probably a "police state": a country where even "legal" actions could be unduly punished at the behest of the controlling entities.

Comment: I've always wondered what "It's a free country" is supposed to mean.  If it's free, I'll take it -- I've always wanted to be a dictator.  Or does it mean that there's no slavery?  There are a lot of countries that have no (overt) slavery, but would probably not be considered "free".

Comment: I have spent the winter in a dictatorship in which people went around saying that they were "free". As far as I could see they just meant the freedom to be unsocialised and uncouth, with no political content at all. But OP might consider "illiberal".

Comment: Which country/countries today would you consider "free in the sense of liberal"?  "A country where something is not legal is not free." I don't know of any country where everything and anything is legal.

Comment: i only mean it in the context of one law. for example: im talking about copyright laws and i would say the USA and Great Britain are non free countries because of restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

A country with a low level of personal freedom would be considered **authoritarian**.

> [authoritarian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/authoritarian) - Favouring or enforcing strict obedience to authority at the expense of personal freedom; showing a lack of concern for the wishes or opinions of others; dictatorial

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of ***a free country*** is ***a dictatorship.***

Answer (score 1):

In this context, ***unfree*** and ***unfreedom*** work. I imagine some people think they sound quite clunky, but I like them.

Also in addition to authoritarian as mentioned by others, there is ***totalitarian***, where the state seeks to maximise control of every aspect of public and private life.